# WPF/C# task async for dummies: How to build a simple UI/BL cooperation?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, task, business-logic

I'm almost completely virgin in threading / backgroundworkers etc.

I am trying to do this:

1. New window shows status of a process (label) and has an ongoing
   XAML-defined animation with a storyboard (three points representing
   a process in the background).
2. Run some background intensive code, that requires some input and
   returns no output.
3. When finished, update the UI with a message
4. Repeat 2 & 3 tens of times with different operations in the background each time.

While the background BL is operating I'd like the UI not to hang, but the continuation of the execution of the next BL method should only execute after the first one has ended and the UI has been updated with the message I'd like to present.

I'd like the slimmest, simplest way to do this. using .Net 4.5, so I believe we're talking Tasks, right?

I've read dozens of Stackoverflow articles and consulted uncle google and aunt MSDN, but it's overwhelming - there are many ways to do this, and I'm a bit lost.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look [at the `EventProgress<T>` object.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/129447/Progress-Reporting-in-C-Async)

Comment: Voted to close as too broad. You should choose approach by yourself, and ask here for details. I'd recommend this series by Stephen Cleary: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx This is definitely a good starting point, and the author is `async`/`await` genius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you're talking about are fairly simple to do with async/await. Since you said you're new to multithreading, I recommend you to read and make yourself familiarize with it. Here is a [good start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) and [this](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)

I assume you can implement #1 yourself and you only need guidance in implementing rest. So, I'll not be talking about it in my post.

Theoretically you need a collection with the list of work needs to be done, then start one by one after the previous one is completed.

To give some code sample

```
List<WorkItem> workItems = ...;//Populate it somehow

private async Task DoWorkMain()
{
    foreach (var item in workItems)
    {
         await DoWork(item);
         //WorkItem completed, Update the UI here,
         //Code here runs in UI thread given that you called the method from UI
    }
}

private Task DoWork(WorkItem item)
{
    //Implement your logic non blocking
}
```

Then somewhere from the UI call

```
await DoWorkMain();
```

`WorkItem` is a class which holds data about the work to be done.

Comment: Thanks, @Sriram Sakthivel. That's the general direction I asked for. Could you please elaborate on `List<WorkItem> workItems = ...;//Populate it somehow`? An example?

Comment: @zazkapulsk You need to add some workitems to the list so that you can execute it. i.e with the parameters you need to work. `workItems.Add(new WorkItem(yourparameter1, parameter2))`. I hope you have the list of work to be done somewhere in your program, that's what is `List<WorkItem> workItems`

Comment: Thanks. That's it. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hmmm, @Sriram Sakthivel - I get an error in the DoWork method: "not all code paths return a value". What should be returned ?

Comment: @zazkapulsk Read the links I have provided to learn how to work with async/await. If you implement `DoWork` as async method, you don't need to return anything but there should be an await keyword inside. Read about how to work with Tasks and TPL in general.

Answer (score -2):

You need to create a thread for processing the data in the background. You can go with parameterised threads and if you want to continue the second execution only after the first is completed, set a boolean variable in the while lop of the thread or write thread synchronization.

Comment: It's a bad idea - to create a thread. Since `ThreadPool` was invented, there's no need to manage threads by hand in most cases. Since TPL (and, especially, `async`/`await`) was released, there's no need to deal with `ThreadPool` directly.